# Can't select rows of specific table in procedure in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a procedure that generates a unique number for some table rows. Kinda manual auto increment.

So, my control of unique numbers is a table `CONTROL_GENERATOR` composed in this structure:

```
|--------------|--------------|
| NM_GENERATOR | NUM_GENERATOR|
|--------------|--------------|
| VARCHAR (50) |   INTEGER    |
|--------------|--------------|
| INC_TAFCAB   | 3            |
|--------------|--------------|
```

And my procedure is defined as the following code:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE [GENERATE_UNIQUE] (
                @INC_GENERATOR VARCHAR(50),
                @MYRET VARCHAR(50) OUTPUT)
AS DECLARE
    @NEW_VALUE INTEGER
BEGIN
   /* [PART 1] - CHECK IF THE TABLE EXISTS IN THE DATABASE */
   IF (SELECT COUNT(NAME) FROM SYSOBJECTS WHERE NAME = 'CONTROL_GENERATOR') = 0
   BEGIN
      SELECT @MYRET = 'TABLE DONT EXISTS'
      RAISERROR (@MYRET,16,1)
      RETURN
   END

   /* [PART 2] - CHECK IF THE COLUMN NM_GENERATOR EXISTS */
   IF (SELECT COUNT(B.NAME)
       FROM
       SYSOBJECTS A,
       SYSCOLUMNS B
       WHERE
             A.NAME = 'CONTROL_GENERATOR' AND
             A.ID   = B.ID AND
             B.NAME = 'NM_GENERATOR') = 0
   BEGIN
      SELECT @MYRET = 'COLUMN "NM_GENERATOR" DONT EXISTS'
      RAISERROR (@MYRET,16,1)
      RETURN
   END

   /* [PART 3] - CHECK IF THE COLUMN NUM_GENERATOR EXISTS */
   IF (SELECT COUNT(B.NAME)
       FROM
       SYSOBJECTS A,
       SYSCOLUMNS B
       WHERE
             A.NAME = 'CONTROL_GENERATOR' AND
             A.ID   = B.ID AND
             B.NAME = 'NUM_GENERATOR') = 0
   BEGIN
      SELECT @MYRET = 'COLUMN "NUM_GENERATOR" DONT EXISTS'
      RAISERROR (@MYRET,16,1)
      RETURN
   END

   /* [PART 4] - CHECK IF THERE IS A GENERATOR WITH THE SPECIFIED NAME */
   IF (SELECT COUNT(NMGEN)
       FROM CONTROL_GENERATOR
       WHERE NM_GENERATOR = @INC_GENERATOR) = 0
   BEGIN
      SELECT @MYRET = UPPER('GENERATOR '+@INC_GENERATOR+' DONT EXISTS')
      RAISERROR (@MYRET,16,1)
      RETURN
   END

   /* [PART 5] - UPDATE GENERATOR TO LAST INSERTED UNIQUE VALUE */
   UPDATE CONTROL_GENERATOR SET @NEW_VALUE = NUM_GENERATOR = NUM_GENERATOR + 1 WHERE     NM_GENERATOR = @INC_GENERATOR

   /* [PART 6] - RETURN WITH THE INCREMENTED VALUE */
   SELECT @MYRET = CAST(@NEW_VALUE AS VARCHAR(50))
   RETURN @MYRET
END

GO
```

When I go to my SQL Client (SQLDBx) and run these SQL commands:

```
DECLARE @RETURNING VARCHAR (50)
EXECUTE GENERATE_UNIQUE 'INC_TAFCAB', @RETURNING OUT
SELECT "@RETURNING" = @RETURNING
```

It returns the correct value `4`, and the next time I run then `5` and so on...

But when I call the procedure inside my application. Passing the exactly same argument `'INC_TAFCAB'` and connecting in the same schema, it fails to pass the verification of `[PART 4]`, the `COUNT(NMGEN)` returns 0. But if I execute the exatcly same select as:

```
SELECT COUNT(NMGEN) FROM CONTROL_GENERATOR WHERE NM_GENERATOR = 'INC_TAFCAB'
```

Then it returns `1`, indicating that a generator with that name exists. I already checked the schema as I said above, and I'm connecting with the same user.

Any idea what I can check that can cause this error? Permissions of the database or something like that?

Comment: Are you using 2012? If so, I would abandon this entirely and go with a sequence. This type of "roll your own" identity type of concept is always a challenge. You have concurrency issues to consider, etc, etc, etc.

Comment: Your code is clearly working it is how you are calling it (which you haven't defined) that is causing the outputs to be not what you expect.  If you ran a trace you will probably see that it works just fine, its the client that is either not getting the output or not interpreting it correctly.

Comment: @SeanLange I'm using 2005, I use it because of concurrency issues! It has been working perfect for me in Oracle the past 5 years.

Comment: @SteveNewton But I don't get a result in client, it prompt an exception. And I know that the argument of the procedure is passing correctly, because the message of the exception raised by the procedure cites the value of the argument. I wish I could trace it, but I don't have access to the MS SQL Server machine, and don't dare to configure remote debugging which requires lots  of time.

Comment: You know the code is running as it suggests this when you run the query manually afterwards, this means your client is executing the code so no problem with user perms and the like.  Where I think its going wrong is picking up the output which allows you to handle a success.  What is the exception?

Comment: @SteveNewton The exception is exactly the same as I throw in the procedure code: `SELECT @MYRET = UPPER('GENERATOR '+@INC_GENERATOR+' DONT EXISTS') RAISERROR (@MYRET,16,1)`

Comment: It's the first time you use the parameter @INC_GENERATOR, suggesting that it does not match the table.  In your exception does it state it correctly?

Comment: @SteveNewton Yes, it is the initial value I passed in the argument: `INC_TAFCAB`

Comment: That really makes no sense if the parameter is exactly the same.  Try to copy the SQL executed from the Debug session directly into a query window, may give you some clue.  Its got to be something obvious.

Comment: @SteveNewton I recreated the CONTROL_GENERATOR table with another name like TBL_CTRL_GENERATOR, and it worked fine. Can't see what was causing this. Anyway, thanks for the help!

Comment: Odd, but at least its resolved!